# css animation plays on page load but not when requested in js

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

So the problem that I'm getting is that I am trying to make a pop cat copy (yes in 2022) and I'm now animating the score with css and javascript. The animation for the score loads when the webpage loads, but not when I click the "Pop Fat". So the css animation works fine (probably).

I know that the css loads only once so I tried to load the css always again when you click but it is pretty heavy and also the screen flashes like 0.3 seconds as the "no css page".

I have then tried to search from google about this, but I only get answers that use the *forwards* *animation-fill-mode*, I tried it but it didn't work. `animation-fill-mode: forwards`

[here is a working jsfiddle for the code](https://jsfiddle.net/PottuGD/pr0dwf6e/23/)

Edit: I updated the fiddle to be more simple but produce the same problem. Also I got the animation to work, but only when I'm **holding** the mouse button down. The animation I am trying to make is a scaling animation.

Comment: I don't see any animation on page load. Also, see how to share a [mcve].

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your description so seeing the code is definitely needed. I wonder if you have listened for the animationend event and cleared the animation CSS for the element (so when you come to set it again it will play again).

Comment: I looked over your jsfiddle and it's not clear what you're trying to animate or how you want to animate it. You can always re-trigger an animation by removing and re-adding a class from the element.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to be more simple (read the Edit section)